# IMEI телефона как ключ для аутентификации на сайте – возможно ль?

Tags: imei, авторизация

Для одного исследовательского проекта сотне испытуемых раздали мобильники, на которых установлен спец. софт, собирающий данные об уровне шума, освещенности, двигательной активности и пр., и отсылающий их на сервер. Данные идентифицируются по IMEI коду аппарата, с которого пришли.

Нужно организовать вход на сайт для испытуемых, где они смогут увидеть какую-то статистику по собранным с их аппарата данным.

Исследование анонимное, и хочется избежать сбора любых данных типа эл. почты или номера телефона. Дело происходит в Европе, тут адовы законы на сей счет. Даже, если все испытуемые – «свои» : )

Как лучше организовать авториазцию/вход на сайт, не регистрируя юзеров, а исходя только из того, что у них сейчас есть этот аппарат?

Пока единственный вариант — заставить моб. разработчиков добавить функцию в ту софтину, чтобы она генерила временный токен, напр. MD5 даты и IMEI аппарата, а сервер бы проверял ее (и +- 1 день на всякий). Т.е. достал телефон, открыл программу, ввел временный токен - вошел, увидил свою статистику.

Как бы вы сделали сие лучше и остроумнее, без доработки моб. клиента?

Comment: А что делать с армией "серых" телефонов у которых один и тот же IMEI ?

Comment: А зачем в этой задаче вообще нужна аутентификация? Исследование же анонимное. 

Пусть все все смотрят, каждый наверное знает свой IMEI, а вот сопоставить чужой с конкретным человеком вряд ли сможет.

Comment: а зачем дата? типа телефон потом другим отдадут и чтоб бывшие юзеры не смотрели уже чужую статистику?  
имхо, лучше было бы не на IMEI зашиваться на на guid. получили guid (в софтине) - отдали испытуемому, по этому гуиду можно смотреть статистику. надо другому аппарат отдать снова получили guid и так далее...  
как что-либо можно сделать, не внося изменения в клиент, понятия не имею.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как раз с точки зрения Европы - лучше сделать им логины типа user1, user2 и т.п.

Можете напечатать их на бумажках свернуть в конвертики, и устроить лотерею :)
Чтоб все точно были уверены, что вы не знаете, кто за каким логином закреплен.

Как раз публикуя имеи вы рискуете нарваться на пошапке, с общей формулировкой, что это индивидуальный ИД, который юзер не может сменить.

Безопаснее - анонимная регистрация на сайте, особенно, если вам не слишком принципиально +- пару человек.

Кстати, если работаете с ВБ или Германией (и Ватикан ещё), то лучше собрать с народа письменные заявы, что они не против сбора вашим ПО вот этих, этих и этих данных в автоматическом режиме. Можете почитать лицензионные условия Яндекс-карт, для мобильных девайсов. Там хорошо написано было.